# Pivoting to multi-index without explicit level names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reshape a dataframe to have two levels of column, without specifying the names of the sub-level.

As an example, initially my data looks like this, with index 'date' and 'product', and then some columns:

```
                    a           b
date    product             
2011-11 foo         1.          2.1 
2011-12 foo         2.432       2.3 
2012-01 bar         0.4         1.7 
2012-01 foo         0.84        1.8 
2014-06 bar         0.          2.  
2014-07 bar         1.68        3.
```

Note that there is one row per date, product combination (index is unique).

I would like to reshape it into a single index, date, moving the product into the column levels:

```
                     foo                   bar
                a           b        a           b
date    
2011-11         1.          2.1      NaN         NaN
2011-12         2.432       2.3      NaN         NaN
2012-01         0.84        1.8      0.4         1.7
2014-06         NaN         NaN      0.          2. 
2014-07         NaN         NaN      1.68        3.
```

I am unsure how to write a pivot, given that the column names a and b are not fixed, and there may be more or less every time this process runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`unstack`** and **`swaplevel`**:

```
df.unstack(1).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

```
product   bar         foo
            a    b      a    b
date
2011-11   NaN  NaN  1.000  2.1
2011-12   NaN  NaN  2.432  2.3
2012-01  0.40  1.7  0.840  1.8
2014-06  0.00  2.0    NaN  NaN
2014-07  1.68  3.0    NaN  NaN
```